# Editing Ini Files In Visual C#

Tags: c#, ini

I am trying to use this to edit an ini, but I cannot seem to get the code to add the section of the ini file into the RichTextbox.

```
        if (myIni.GetSection(String.Format("[{0}]", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper())) != null);
        {
            mySection = new IniFile.IniSection(myIni, String.Format("{0}", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper()));
            foreach (IniFile.IniSection.IniKey key in mySection.Keys)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("{0}={1}{2}", key.Name, key.Value, Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Have you debugged? Is `mySection` ever anything? Does `mySection.Keys` contain data?

Comment: @RonBeyer How would I check for that?

Comment: By using a debugger? It's c# programming fundamentals...

Comment: @RonBeyer means using something like a Console.Writeline or the debugging features of your IDE (visual studio) to check if mySection contains the right data

Comment: It seems that `mySection`'s value is `{IniFile.IniSection}` and `mySection.Keys`'s value is `{System.Collections.Hashtable.ValueCollection}`.

Comment: Usually C# programs don't use ini for configuration, it is much more common to use XML now. The usual method is to use the `app.config` file, it even has [a nice editor built in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx) to visual studio to manage the keys and values.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm creating a program that edits the ini file of another program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old existing ini calls from windows:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
        int size, string filePath);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
        string key, string val, string filePath);
```

...

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
GetPrivateProfileString("section", "key", "default", temp, 255, inifilename);
String value = temp.ToString();


WritePrivateProfileString("section", "key", value, inifilename);
```